# Sampling from a skewed distribution

Tags: sampling, survey-sampling

So I have a dataset with around 40,000 unique free text descriptions of purchased goods. I also know the spend on each of these unique descriptions, and the distribution of spend is long tailed.

Some of these unique free text descriptions represent the same item, and the spend on descriptions that represent the same item should be consolidated, but there's no systematical way to match the ones that belong together. The only way is to analyze each description, and figure out which ones go together. However, it's not feasible to go thru the 40,000 descriptions and analyze them one by one.

I want to draw a representative and manageable sample, which I can go through one by one, consolidate spend where needed, and infer from this consolidated, sampled, spend the spend distribution of the whole population.

Intuitively, I figured simple random sampling wouldn't work, because I'm gonna miss out on much of the descriptions that are in the long tail (and which represent more spend and ultimately are more relevant to describe spend).

I think conceptually, what I would like would be to oversample from the long tail, and then draw a representative random sample from the high density part of the distribution of spend. But I do not know of the proper way to do this, in order to ensure a valid inference from the sample.

Adding an example because someone suggested my problem wasn't clear:

There's  N <= 40,000 unique items and 40,000 unique descriptions. I don't know N, but it's likely in the thousands. Each description refer to one or more items. I need to know which descriptions refer to which items in order to consolidate the spend that belongs to those descriptions as belonging to the same item.

Say my (descriptions, spend) were:

1. itm1, 10 USD
2. i1, 10 USD
3. item1, 5 USD
4. i2, 1 USD
5. it2, 2 USD

I should be able to figure out that underlyingly, the descriptions refer to either item 1 or item 2, and the consolidated spend is:
item 1: 25 USD and item 2: 3 USD

However, I have 40k unique descriptions and likely thousands of items, so it's not feasible to go through the 40k descriptions. Additionaly, these 40k descriptions don't relate to the underlying item in as straightforward way as in my example, so it's hard to associate via unsupervised learning (tried already).

What is the theoretically correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: It is not clear what the tetxual descriptors are good for and what you mean by "spend distribution". It seems to me that "spend" is just a random value and its distribution thus is a probability density of a univariat variable. You can estimate it with kernel density etsimation. If you prefer a parametric model, a Pareto distribution might fit, but you should check this beforehand with van der Wijk's law.

Comment: They're good for figuring out which item they refer to. There's  N <= 40,000 unique items and 40,000 unique descriptions. I don't know N, but it's likely in the thousands. Each description refer to one or more items. I need to know which descriptions refer to which items in order to consolidate the spend that belongs to those descriptions as belonging to the same item.

Comment: So In other words, this is a clustering problem based on two features: textual description (string) and spend (number)?

Comment: Yeah, you could see it like that. But it's too complex to solve it via unsupervised learning, I've tried. The descriptions are not that good to begin with. They can be solved by a human with a bit of research, googling, asking around, but not systematically. That's why I want to sample and make it manageable. I edited the OP with an example if it's of any help.

Comment: Since I posted this, I've been thinking that I should stratify by top dollar, and just sample the whole strata where the spend is worth my time, and do random sampling in lower spend strata. It makes sense to me, but also seems a bit arbitrary, and i don't know if it's theoretically correct.